# Is there something missing in the Flutter introduction?

Tags: flutter

I am currently learning Flutter and followed the [official introduction](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/codelab) on the Flutter website, which worked without any problems. On the page there was a link to [part 2](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/first-flutter-app-pt2#3) on Google Developers Codelab.

First there is some information, including a code template for the second part, which is the same as my code on part 1. Then the actual coding part starts and here is the problem. It says to make changes in a widget that I don't have and wasn't mentioned before. The problem is that I know basically nothing about flutter and don't know where it belongs and also the whole context is missing, so I don't know what else is in the widget.

At the end of the chapter is again a code template given in case of problems, but again there is no trace of the widget. Maybe I've overlooked something, but I'm pretty sure that there is an error at this point.

### Edit

This is the problem:

[image: This is the problem]

And this is their [code template](https://github.com/flutter/codelabs/blob/master/startup_namer/step5_add_icons/lib/main.dart) without any trace of a _buildRow() method

Comment: Did you look at dart that is programming language of flutter ? if you didn't, before dive deep into flutter framework, you need to learn dart

Comment: Cool, but you did not answer my question.

Comment: What widget are you talking about? Add code showing where you are or add a picture showing where you're lost in the introduction.

Comment: @pskink this is not the problem. They are talking about a _buildRow() method, which is completly new at this point. I will edit my question to make it more clear.

Comment: No these two are different things. If you follow the introduction further the _buildRow() method is used again and again. But I found a solution on Github in the meantime. It is indeed a mistake in the introduction. For anyone wondering here is the thread: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/100362